# Trying to replace a number from a dictionary(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hashtable

In my code I am trying to code something like a Hash Table and I am working on the part where you add numbers to the table can someone help me? My code here:

```
num = input("Number you want to insert:")
table = {"1":0, "2":0, "3":0 }
print(table)
def insert(table):
     find_key = int(num) % len(table)
      # Linear probing?
     for i in range(len(table)):            
        if i == find_key:
            dict[i] = int(num)
            print(table)
     print(i)
     return i
print(table)
insert(table)
```

The error is
    TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment

Comment: What were you hoping `dict[i] = int(num)` would achieve? `dict` is a type. You are trying to assign to it, which wont work. `dict`s are hash tables already, so its unclear what your aim is.

Comment: `dict[i] = ...` should be `table[i] = ...`. Beside that, instead of using indexes (0, 1, 2, ..) to access items, you need to use keys ("1", "2", "3") (Iterating a dictionary will yields keys)!

Comment: Dictionaries *ARE* hashtables.   If you are going to try to implement one yourself, I would recommend you use *lists* instead if you want to implement a hashtable yourself

Comment: @falsetru I am trying to replace the number not add another group.

Comment: `table[i] = ...` will replace the item if there is the same key.

Comment: @falsetru what do you mean I that and the code came out like this {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, 0: 3} I want {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 3} or code suppose to be like this table[i] = int(num)

Comment: Then, simply: `table['3'] = 3`.

Comment: @falsetru then whats the point of me using the input? I want the user to do everything not me but this works table["3"] = int(num) but I still want the computer to find the spot by itself but not changing it every single time.

Comment: `table[num] = int(num)`

Comment: @falsetru You might as well add that as an answer.

Comment: @Gokul, I posted an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo: `dict[...] = ...` should be `table[...] = ...`

---

You don't need to implement hash table yourself. Python dictionaries are hashtables.

Simply assigning to a dictionary will add (or replace if there's the given key) item to it.

```
def insert(table, num):
     table[num] = int(num)  # not dict[...] = ...

num = input("Number you want to insert:")
table = {"1":0, "2":0, "3":0 }
print(table)  # before insert
insert(table, num)
print(table)  # after insert
```